# How to update value from Router params inside component?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, breadcrumbs

I'm using Angular5.
I have Header component.
Goal: I need to implement **breadcrumbs** in header.
My view:
Routing already implemented, I just need to:

1. parse ID from URL
2. get Item from BackEnd
3. get Name
4. set Name as Breadcrumb to Header component

**My current progress:**

I can parse ID from URL using following code:

```
this.activatedRouter.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
    });
```

Now, in template I have:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a routerLink="/items" routerLinkActive="active">Items</a></li>
    <li>{{id}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Question**: How to update ID value in Component each time after new route executed?

***For example:***

1. I'm on Items Page => My URL localhost:4002/items
2. I clicked on Item, and redirected to Items page => My URL localhost:4002/items/34 => My Breadcrumbs = Items > 34

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

this.route.routerState.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params['id'];
});
```

your component will be updated with the new state

Comment: Where should I Put second part? I mean "this.route.routerState......" ?

Comment: i updated the answer , just replace this.activatedRouter.params.subscribe by this.route.routerState.params.subscribe

Comment: Ok, But where should I do it?
In onInit? or onChanges?

Comment: Wrong, Component was initialized only 1 time, when URL was localhost/items.
When I clicked on Item, and load item page, my URL changed to loaclhost/items/5 , but onInit was not triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val: NavigationEnd) => {
...action with val.url variable
    }
}
```

Each time, after redirect you will get data from your URL.